# Trouble returning a struct from a function

Tags: c++, function, struct

I want to have a function return a struct.  So, in my header file, I defined the struct and the function signature.  In my code file, I then have the actual function.  I get errors about "unknown type name".  Everything appears to be following a very standard format for this.

Any ideas why this isn't working?

TestClass.h

```
class TestClass {
public:

    struct foo{
        double a;
        double b;
    };

    foo trashme(int x);

}
```

TestClass.cpp

```
#include "testClass.h"

foo trashme(int x){

    foo temp;
    foo.a = x*2;
    foo.b = x*3;

    return(foo)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo` isn't in the global namespace, so `trashme()` can't find it.  What you want is this:

```
TestClass::foo TestClass::trashme(int x){ //foo and trashme are inside of TestClass

    TestClass::foo temp; //foo is inside of TestClass
    temp.a = x*2; //note: temp, not foo
    temp.b = x*3; //note: temp, not foo

    return(temp) //note: temp, not foo

}
```

Comment: His `trashme` function is a member function, so it should be qualified, and he forgot a semicolon at the end of his return :)

Comment: bah, I fixed the answer, it wasn't as big a change as I originally thought.

Answer (score 3):

`foo` is a child class of `TestClass`, and `trashme` is a member function of `TestClass`, so you need to qualify them:

```
TestClass::foo TestClass::trashme(int x){

    foo temp;  // <-- you don't need to qualify it here, because you're in the member function scope
    temp.a = x*2;  // <-- and set the variable, not the class
    temp.b = x*3;

    return temp;  // <-- and return the variable, not the class, with a semicolon at the end
                  // also, you don't need parentheses around the return expression

}
```